# Why do we need to use flatMap?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am starting to use RxJS and I don't understand why in this example we need to use a function like `flatMap` or `concatAll`; where is the array of arrays here?

```
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');

var responseMetastream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

responseMetastream.subscribe(url => {console.log(url)})
```

If someone can visually explain what is happening, it will be very helpful.

Comment: this answer is great because of the valuable references that it provides, but rxjs terminology doesn't translate well into English. (pictures are better). That's why I recommend instead running simple examples like this one, or more complex examples in the rxjs repo and adding ".do" operators before and after a flatmap and map operator, then just setting a breakpoint with the Chrome debugger. you'll see instantly that each produces a different output

Comment: I think if `flatMap` would have been named `mapThenFlatten`, then it would be less confusing.

Comment: I personally don't like the example. Why would you subscribe to a url string observable. Of course it makes you think the 'rx' way, but in terms of code I don't find intuitive, unless you use it long enough so you don't question it anymore. But looks like a lot of overkill to me. No wonder people have trouble understanding.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

When I started to have a look at `Rxjs` I also stumbled on that stone. What helped me is the following:

- documentation from reactivex.io . For instance, for `flatMap`: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html
- documentation from rxmarbles : http://rxmarbles.com/. You will not find `flatMap` there, you must look at `mergeMap` instead (another name).
- the introduction to Rx that you have been missing: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754. It addresses a very similar example. In particular it addresses the fact that a promise is akin to an observable emitting only one value.
- finally looking at the type information from RxJava. Javascript not being typed does not help here. Basically if `Observable<T>` denotes an observable object which pushes values of type T, then `flatMap` takes a function of type `T' -> Observable<T>` as its argument, and returns `Observable<T>`. `map` takes a function of type `T' -> T` and returns `Observable<T>`.

  Going back to your example, you have a function which produces promises from an url string. So `T' : string`, and `T : promise`. And from what we said before `promise : Observable<T''>`, so `T : Observable<T''>`, with `T'' : html`. If you put that promise producing function in `map`, you get `Observable<Observable<T''>>` when what you want is `Observable<T''>`: you want the observable to emit the `html` values. `flatMap` is called like that because it flattens (removes an observable layer) the result from `map`. Depending on your background, this might be chinese to you, but everything became crystal clear to me with typing info and the drawing from here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should be able to simplify `return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));` to `return jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl);` as `flatMap` also accepts a selector function which returns a promise i.e. function of type `T' -> Promise`.

Comment: Wow, that GitHub Gist (https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) is bloody fantastic. I recommend it to anyone working with any ReactiveX libraries like RxJS.

Comment: @JacobStamm i agree . Just makes things easier .

Comment: What does this syntax mean: `T’ -> T`? I understand the `T` as a generic, but what is the apostrophe and not-fat arrow?

Comment: You can replace T' by X or Y without changing the meaning anywhere in the answer. The arrow is Haskell notation for type signature. So T' -> T is the signature for a function which takes an element of type T' and returns an element of type T

Answer (score 139):

```
['a','b','c'].flatMap(function(e) {
    return [e, e+ 'x', e+ 'y',  e+ 'z'  ];
});
//['a', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'b', 'bx', 'by', 'bz', 'c', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz']


['a','b','c'].map(function(e) {
    return [e, e+ 'x', e+ 'y',  e+ 'z'  ];
});
//[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
```

You use flatMap when you have an Observable whose results are more Observables.

If you have an observable which is produced by an another observable you can not filter, reduce, or map it directly because you have an Observable not the data. If you produce an observable choose flatMap over map; then you are okay.

As in second snippet, if you are doing async operation you need to use flatMap.

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.interval(100).take(10).map(function(num){
    return num+1
});
source.subscribe(function(e){
    console.log(e)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.interval(100).take(10).flatMap(function(num){
    return Rx.Observable.timer(100).map(() => num)
});
source.subscribe(function(e){
    console.log(e)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 60):

**People tend to over complicate things** by giving the definition which says:

> flatMap transform the items emitted by an Observable into
> Observables, then flatten the emissions from those into a single
> Observable

I swear this definition still confuses me but I am going to explain it in the simplest way which is by using an example

**Our Simple Example**

1- We have an observable which returns a simple URL string.

2- We have to use that URL to make a second HTTP call.

3- The second HTTP call will return an observable containing the data we need.

So we can visualize the situation like this:

```
Observable 1
    |_
       Make Http Call Using Observable 1 Data (returns Observable_2)
            |_
               The Data We Need
```

so as you can see we can't reach the data we need directly

so to retrieve the data we can use just normal subscriptions like this:

```
Observable_1.subscribe((URL) => {
         Http.get(URL).subscribe((Data_We_Need) => {
                  console.log(Data_We_Need);
          });
});
```

this works but as you can see we have to nest subscriptions to get our data this currently does not look bad but imagine we have 10 nested subscriptions that would become unmaintainable!

so a better way to handle this is just to use the operator `flatMap` which will do the same thing but makes us avoid that nested subscription:

```
Observable_1
    .flatMap(URL => Http.get(URL))
    .subscribe(Data_We_Need => console.log(Data_We_Need));
```

Answer (score 36):

`flatMap` transform the items emitted by an Observable into new Observables, then flattens the emissions from those into a single Observable.

Check out the scenario below where `get("posts")` returns an Observable that is "flattened" by `flatMap`.

```
myObservable.map(e => get("posts")).subscribe(o => console.log(o));
// this would log Observable objects to console.  

myObservable.flatMap(e => get("posts")).subscribe(o => console.log(o));
// this would log posts to console.
```

Comment: Nice, simple answer. I think this might be the best.

Comment: "flatMap transform the items emitted by an Observable into new Observables, then flattens the emissions from those into a single Observable." This is excellent stuff.

Answer (score 23):

Simple:

```
[1,2,3].map(x => [x, x * 10])
// [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]

[1,2,3].flatMap(x => [x, x * 10])
// [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]]
```

Answer (score 15):

It's not an array of arrays. It's an observable of observable(s).

The following returns an observable stream of string.

```
requestStream
  .map(function(requestUrl) {
    return requestUrl;
  });
```

While this returns an observable stream of observable stream of json

```
requestStream
  .map(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });
```

`flatMap` flattens the observable automatically for us so we can observe the json stream directly

Comment: It is hard to understand this concept, can you please add comments to visual what you mean "returns an observable stream of observable stream of json". thanks.

Comment: @user233232, like [x,x,x,x] to [[xxx],[[xxx],[xxx]]]

Comment: The key to understanding the first sentence is understanding that `flatMap` (and `map`) aren't special to arrays. It's possible to define these operations on any generic container or wrapper, including arrays, dictionaries, "optionals", reactive streams, promises, pointers, and even functions themselves. 

This is an emergent property of a mathematical construct called the monad. All the examples above meet the requirements for being a monad, and so they all can be given a definition of `map` and a `flatMap` (with some caveats).

Answer (score 14):

An Observable is an object that emits a stream of events: Next, Error and Completed.

When your function returns an Observable, it is not returning a stream, but an instance of Observable. The `flatMap` operator simply maps that instance to a stream.

That is the behaviour of `flatMap` when compared to `map`: Execute the given function and flatten the resulting object into a stream.

Answer (score 14):

Here to show equivalent implementation of a flatMap using subscribes.

Without flatMap:

```
this.searchField.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)
.subscribe(
  term => this.searchService.search(term)
  .subscribe( results => {
      console.log(results);  
      this.result = results;
    }
  );
);
```

With flatMap:

```
this.searchField.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)
    .flatMap(term => this.searchService.search(term))
    .subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      this.result = results;
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BHGmEcdS5eQGX703eRRE?p=preview

Hope it could help.

Olivier.

Comment: For anyone like me wondering why pipe is missing, pipe is used from rxjs 5.5 and above, but operators were combined with `.` in earlier versions as seen in this response.

Answer (score 7):

With flatMap

```
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');

var responseMetastream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

responseMetastream.subscribe(json => {console.log(json)})
```

Without flatMap

```
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');

var responseMetastream = requestStream
  .map(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

responseMetastream.subscribe(jsonStream => {
  jsonStream.subscribe(json => {console.log(json)})
})
```

Answer (score 5):

> flatMap transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables,
> then flatten the emissions from those into a single Observable

I am not stupid but had to read this 10 times to get it.

Map works like a for...each  on each item in the array and transforms the items in the array but keeps the array as it is :

```
[1,2,3].map(x => [x, x * 10])
// [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
```

Flatmap does the same as map but also "flattens" the array :

```
[1,2,3].flatMap(x => [x, x * 10])
// [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]
```

> **flatMap** :
>
> 1. **map**: transform *) emitted items into Observables.
> 2. **flat**: then merge those Observables as one Observable.

*) The transform word says the item can be transformed in something else.

Then the **merge** operator becomes clear to, it does the flattening without the mapping. Why not calling it **mergeMap**? It seems there is also an Alias **mergeMap** with that name for **flatMap**.

Answer (score 2):

> **flatMap is used to flatten an array of arrays into a single array.**
>
> ***map* simply converts one array to an other array. For example, suppose you have a list of person objects like this:**

```
const friends = [
    {name: 'Dave', kids: ['Max', 'Jack']},
    {name: 'Max', kids: ['Sam', 'Alex', 'Megan']},
    {name: 'Jordan', kids: ['Mason', 'Cameron', 'Kaylin']}
];
```

But what you really need is an array of person names (i.e. strings: [“Dave”, “Max”, “Jordan”]). To convert this array of person object to array of strings, you would first define your mapping function like this:

```
const mapFunction = p -> p.name;
```

Then, use array.map like this:

```
const names = friends.map(mapFunction);
```

which returns:

```
["Dave", "Max", "Jordan"]
```

*flatMap* is similar to map in that you are converting one array into another array. But there are a few subtle differences:
First of all, map is generally a one-to-one thing. The mapping function takes one object in and returns one object out:

```
p -> p.name
```

This means that 3 person objects in will produce 3 names out.

*flatMap*, on the other hand, is a one-to-many thing. The mapping function takes one object in but returns an array out:

```
p -> p.kids
```

The net result: 3 person objects in will produce 8 kid names out. Thus, this code:

```
const mapFunction = p -> p.kids;
const kidNames = friends.flatMap(mapFunction);
```

will return:

```
["Max", "Jack", "Sam", "Alex", "Megan", "Mason", "Cameron", "Kaylin"]
```