# Change Interval/settings of observable after creation

Tags: javascript, observable, rxjs, reactivex

In RxJS how would I change the interval setting after creation?

So far I have this, but it doesn't work

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .map(function (data) { return "Hello World " + data; });

observable.subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(function () {
  observable.interval(3000);
}, 3000);
```

It says "TypeError: observable.interval is not a function at sixage.js:10:14"

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sixage/4/edit?html,js,console)

**Edit**:

This was the final product after using the accepted answer.

```
var intervalUpdateS = new Rx.Subject();
var observable = intervalUpdateS.startWith(500).flatMapLatest(function(intvl){
  return Rx.Observable.interval(intvl);
})
.map (function (data) { return "Hello World " + data; });

observable.subscribe(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});

setTimeout(function () {
  intervalUpdateS.onNext(3000)
}, 3000);
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sixage/9/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interval` is defined on the 'class' `Rx.Observable`, not at the prototype level, i.e. not on every instance of `Rx.Observable`. So `observable.interval`  on an observable instance will definitely give you that error.

If you are the source of modification of the interval, I can only think of using a subject to push your modifications. This would work that way:

```
var intervalUpdateS = new Rx.Subject();
var observable = intervalUpdateS.flatMapLatest(function(intvl){
    return Rx.Observable.interval(intvl);
})
.map (function (data) { return "Hello World " + data; });
```

Then you change the interval with `intervalUpdateS.onNext(newValue);`

Haven't tested but hopefully should work as is.

About subjects : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md

About flatMap : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html, and [Why we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)