# how to re-subscribe after unsubscribing an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have created a socketService where i am continously getting data updates and on my component i am subscribing my getUpdates Observable.

I have to unsubscribe on `stop` action and subscribe again on `start` action button.

Unsubscribe works well on `stop` action but after that it doesnt subscribe again on `start` action button.

Here is my socketService:

```
getUpdates() {
    let sub = new Subject();
    let subObservable = from(kioskSub)

   this.socket.on('receive', (updates: any) => {
     sub.next(updates);
   });
   this.socket.on(`master_receive`, (status: any) => {
        sub.next(JSON.stringify(status));
        if (status.action && status.action === 'stop') {
            sub.complete();
        } // i want to stop subscription here
        if (status.action && status.action === 'start') {
            sub.next(JSON.stringify(status));
        } // and start here
    });
   return subObservable;
}
```

Component: // where i  am subscribing getUpdates

```
 this.subscription = this.socketService.getUpdates().subscribe((latestdata: string) => {
       this.status = JSON.parse(latestStatus);
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Subject `sub` to subscribe/unsubscribe according to the value of status.action. `sub.complete()` completes the observable stream and so no more values will be emitted by the observable.

```
 getUpdates() {
    let sub = new Subject();
    let subObservable = from(kioskSub)

   this.socket.on('receive', (updates: any) => {
     sub.next(updates);
   });
   this.socket.on(`master_receive`, (status: any) => {
        sub.next(JSON.stringify(status));
        if (status.action && status.action === 'stop') {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        } // i want to stop subscription here
        if (status.action && status.action === 'start') {
            sub.next(JSON.stringify(status));
        } // and start here
    });
   return sub;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but above solution doesnt work for me, as i am getting ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl errr