# Change observable interval through input

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using a service which "pings" my server and returns the response time. I then display this in a chart.

My first approach (without being able to change intervals) was this:

```
Observable.interval(2500)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          let timeStart: number = performance.now();

          this._http.get(this.url)
            .subscribe((data) => {
              let timeEnd: number = performance.now();

              let ping: number = timeEnd - timeStart;
              this.ping = ping;
              this.pingStream.next(ping);
            });
        });
}
```

This gets called in my app.component cunstructor:

```
this.pingService.pingStream.subscribe(ping => {
         this.ping = ping;
         NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.pop();
         NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.splice(0, 0, this.ping);
      })
```

I'm getting the "ping" and put it into my chartdata. Works fine. 
Now I want to change the intervall.
Therefore I created a streamintervall.ts which is only exporting a variable called INTVL. 
I tried to use the answer in this post : [Change Intervall/settings of observable after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058398/change-interval-settings-of-observable-after-creation)

So now I'm at this state, which doesn't work. My chartdata is counting from 0 on.

```
   observable = this.pingStream.startWith(INTVL)
   .switchMap((INTVL) => { return Observable.interval(INTVL) });
       constructor(private _http: Http) {
          this.observable.map((data) => {
             let timeStart: number = performance.now();
             this._http.get(this.url)
                .subscribe((data) => {
                   let timeEnd: number = performance.now();
                   let ping: number = timeEnd - timeStart;
                   this.ping = ping;
                   this.pingStream.next(ping);
                });
          })
```

In my appcomponent I have an input-textbox with a 2way binding to intvl = INTVL.
I really don't know how to deal with this, because rxjs is kind of hard to get into and I am not really that experienced neither, so any detailed help would be appreciated very much.

If you need more information, tell me.

EDIT: Second approach - I am now creating a new Stream on button click with the input interval :
pingservice.ts:

```
createNew(intvl: number) {
      this.pingStream = new Subject<number>();
      Observable.interval(intvl)
        .subscribe((data) => {
          let timeStart: number = performance.now();
          this._http.get(this.url)
            .subscribe((data) => {
              let timeEnd: number = performance.now();
              let ping: number = timeEnd - timeStart;
              this.ping = ping;
              this.pingStream.next(ping);
            });
        });
   }
```

app.component.ts:

```
newSubscription() {
      console.log(this.pingService.pingStream.isUnsubscribed);
      if (!this.pingService.pingStream.isUnsubscribed) {
         this.pingService.pingStream.unsubscribe();
      }
      if (this.pingService.pingStream.isUnsubscribed) {
         this.pingService.createNew(this.intvl)
         this.pingService.pingStream.subscribe(ping => {
            this.ping = ping;
            NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.pop();
            NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.splice(0, 0, this.ping);
         })
      }
   }
```

So, stopping the pingService works, the new Stream gets created and uses the correct intervall. Now I have another issue: When subscribing to pingStream after creating the new one, I also subscribe to every other pingStream created before (or at least I think I do), which leads into multiple streams delivering my data. 5 clicks = 5 streams. Is there a way to "destroy" those streams and create a new one after?

Comment: Did you see [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058398/change-interval-settings-of-observable-after-creation) ?

Comment: Yep, as it is linked in my question.

Comment: Ok.  I think I know what the problem is but I want to be able to reproduce it before saying something. Can you make a plunker ?

Comment: I am not used to plunker and don't know how to get stuff working with it. I am sorry. :/ But feel free to say what you think the problem might be!

Comment: I've not used ng2 and not sure if this fits your needs, but, here is an example using a select box to change the interval based on its change event http://jsbin.com/remifoxisu/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be using a `Subject` to emit the wanted interval and then use a combination of switchMap and flatMap. You can pause pinging by unsubscribing from `interval$`. To resume pinging resubscribe and call `setInterval` again. Or use a `BehaviorSubject`.

```
interval$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

constructor(){
  this.interval$
    .switchMap((int: number) => Observable  //switch to Observable with new interval
      .interval(int)
      .flatMap(() => StreamOfPings) //execute time measurement function
    )
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}

setInterval(newInterval: number){
  this.interval$.next(newInterval);
}
```