# How to combine interval stream with Promise stream in RxJs and get the values?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm learning RxJs and it's pretty cool. I'm trying to create a page where the Ajax call is interval so the data will be refreshing every 5 seconds. So I thought I would be doing this.

```
var ajax = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  return resolve('test');
});

var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .map(function(i) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(ajax);
  });

source1.subscribe(function(res) {
    res.subscribe(function(pro) {
    console.log(pro);
  })
});
```

However, the fact that I need to do two `subscribe`s got me thinking that I might be doing something wrong here. I'm not sure if I'm going the right direction?

What I want is a stream of promises that will be fetched every 5 seconds.

Here's my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/2y179dgg/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` operator. Have a look at the [jsbin here](https://jsfiddle.net/2y179dgg/2/).

```
var ajax = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  return resolve('test');
});

var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .flatMap(function(i) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(ajax);
  });

source1.subscribe(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

There are extensive examples of use of flatMap available on SO.

You can also consult:

- From SO : [Why we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)
- the nicely presented : [The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754)
- Official doc : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md
- Illustrative marbles : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Comment: if you want to save your ordering of promises you can use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` But more better for promises to use `flatMapLatest`

Comment: if you replace 'test' by a random string like Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5), you can see that the output variable doesn't change. Is there a way to force Promise to be executed at each interval?

Comment: promise are only ever resolved once so yeah that is the expected behavior. If at every interval you want a different promise, then do just that. `var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .flatMap(function(i) {
    return makeYourPromiseHere(i);
  });`

Comment: Thx Captain Obvious! :)