# Is it possible somehow call async Ionic Storage synchronously?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-http

I'm trying to create a class for working with API on top of `Angular2 HTTP` class. The main thing is that I need to add custom auth header which is available after user authorized.

The main problem is that the token is stored in Ionic Storage module from which it can be only be obtained asynchronously, but I need to return the specific type....

```
export class APIRequest extends Http {

    private storage : Storage;

    constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, options);

        this.storage = new Storage;
    }

    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        if (typeof url === 'string') {
            url = AppConfig.API_SERVER + url
        } else {
            url.url = AppConfig.API_SERVER + url.url
        }

        this.storage.get('authToken').then(token => {
            if (typeof url === 'string') {
                if (!options) {
                    options = {headers: new Headers()};
                }

                options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            } else {
                url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            }
            // Here I need to return 
        }, err => {
            // throw some error
        })

        return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
    }
}
```

So basically I need somehow to put `return super.request(url, options)...` to the promise of the storage and return when i get that token.

Comment: why cant you use ``return storage.get().then(fn).then( token => { return super.request() }) ``

Comment: @raj because of `: Observable<Response>`

Comment: not an expert on ``Observables`` but how about making an observable out of promise with ``fromPromise`` and then using ``flatMap`` to return ``request`` observale.

Comment: @raj could provide any example?

Comment: Guess you got the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Close to being a duplicate. (Couln't find it)

At least, the answer can be applied to the same problem. If you want to keep the returning `Observable` a fix would be to convert your `Promise` (`this.storage.get`) to an `Observable`.

After, you can use a operator like `flapMap` to return the value of `super.request`.

(**Note**: Compiler doesn't understand that it's returning a `Response` now, so change return type to `Observable<any>` (will still return `Response`))

```
export class APIRequest extends Http {

    private storage : Storage;

    constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, options);

        this.storage = new Storage;
    }
    // any return type (will return Response object but compiler doesn't understand that)
    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        if (typeof url === 'string') {
            url = AppConfig.API_SERVER + url
        } else {
            url.url = AppConfig.API_SERVER + url.url
        }

        //convert the Promise to an Observable
        val storageObservable = Observable.fromPromise(this.sotrage.get('authToken'));

        // rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap
        return storageObservable.flatMap(token => {
            if (typeof url === 'string') {
                if (!options) {
                    options = {headers: new Headers()};
                }

                options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            } else {
                url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            }
            // the value that will be returned
            return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
        }, err => {
            // throw some error
        })


    }
}
```

Useful links:

- documentation from reactivex.io . For instance, for flatMap: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html
- [Why we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)

Comment: I think ``return`` is missing ?

Comment: @raj thanks for pointing out! You're right, edited the answer

Comment: Did work out after all? Was debugging it at the moment haha

Comment: @Ivaro18 sorry for delay, but just tested... There is an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined(…)` when trying to do the request. I think because it returns not `Response`