# Return observable from observable in angular 2

Tags: angular

In following code snippet. First I am getting lat lng from GeoCode service that returns Observable.After that I am making http call that again returns an observable

```
 getData(next?) {

       return this.geoCode.getCurrentLocation().map(latlng => {
           console.log(latlng);
            var url = this.API_URL + "?location=" + latlng + "&radius=" + this.radius;
            if (next != undefined) {
                url = this.API_URL + "?location=" + latlng + "&radius=" + this.radius + "&next=" + next;
            }
            return this._http.get(url).map(res=>res.json());

        });

};
```

above method is returning `Observable<Observable<any>>` but I want to return  `Observable<any>`

Comment: Use the switchMap operator. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `flatMap` in place of map :

```
 getData(next?) {           
       return this.geoCode.getCurrentLocation().flatMap(latlng => { //HERE !
           console.log(latlng);
            let url = this.API_URL + "?location=" + latlng + "&radius=" + this.radius;
            if (next != undefined) {
                url = this.API_URL + "?location=" + latlng + "&radius=" + this.radius + "&next=" + next;
            }
            return this._http.get(url).flatMap(res=>res.json()); //AND HERE !

        });

};
```

A great reading here : [Why we need to use flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-we-need-to-use-flatmap)

Comment: mergeMap for RXJS 5