# How Can I convert Observable<Observable<Organization>[]> to Observable<Organization[]>?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am using ngrx/store

```
.map((p: Observable<Organization>[]) => {
        return new usersActions.GetOrganizationSuccess(p);
      })
```

GetOrganizationSuccess action takes Organization[] as payload

How Can I convert (p) from `Observable<Organization>[]`  to `Organization[]` ?

Comment: Use a flatMap/switchMap, not a regular map, on the previous step.

Comment: Are you have an example?

Comment: Did you search for one? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33471526/3001761

Comment: Also you can change expecting parameter for `GetOrganizationSuccess` to `Observable<Organization>[]`

Answer (score 0):

subscribe it, something like:

```
.subscribe((users: User[]) => {

            // do stuff with our data here.
            // ....
            // asign data to our class property in the end
            // so it will be available to our template
            this.users = users
        })
```

Comment: I dislike using subscribe in service as It may cause memory leak