# How to pass subscribed data as input to other function?

Tags: angular, rxjs

`getActiveId` function will return me the `ID`, based on the ID retuned I need to make another HTTP call to fetch the data using the function `getOpenIssues`.

So in my component, I subscribed to these functions I could see the `ID` is returned by `getActiveId`.

I passed the `ID` to `getOpenIssues` function, it throws id is not defined.

After searching through net, it is not possible to access variables outside the subscribed method.

Is that case how Do i pass the ID to other function ?

Please help, I'm not able to proceed further.

**Service.ts**

```
getActiveId() {
  return this.http.get<any>(apiUrl);
}
getOpenIssues(id: string) {
  return this.http.get<any>(Url);
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.service.getActiveId()
.subscribe(response => this.id = response.id) // Returns ID 22407

this.service.getOpenIssues(this.id) // Should pass the ID 22407
.subscribe((response) => { })
```

Comment: Use faltMap.
[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-do-we-need-to-use-flatmap)

Answer (score 1):

In your `.component.ts`, since both the functions are asynchronous, your `getOpenIssues` gets called before completion of `getActiveId`.

Hence you can make following changes :

```
this.service.getActiveId()
.subscribe(response => {
  this.id = response.id;
  this.service.getOpenIssues(this.id).subscribe(issues=>console.log(issues));// Returns ID 22407
  })
```

You can also take a look at different `map` operators of RxJS

```
this.service.getActiveId()
    .concatMap((id)=>this.service.getOpenIssues(id))
    .subscribe(issues=>console.log(issues))
```

Answer (score 0):

Components can have 2 methods getActiveId() and getOpenIssues(). Now we need to call getActiveId() which will call first service based on the service's response, call another method of same component (which will call another service if required).

```
getActiveId() {
this.service.getActiveId()
.subscribe(response => {
this.id = response.id;
this.getOpenIssues();
});
}

getOpenIssues() {
this.service.getOpenIssues(this.id)
.subscribe(issues=> //Your logic);
}`
```

Comment: NO, @Sushil, bette ruse switchMap or flatMap

Comment: since response  of  1 service will be the input to another service, so we have to work in my way. if calls were independent then obviously we can use flatmap or switchmap as per case.