# How to run two function one by one using Rxjava when functions are running on different thread

Tags: android, rx-java

```
    fun A(){
        thread {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
           //MyCode

        }
    }

    fun B(){
        thread {
            //MyCode
        }
    }
}
```

need to call 1st A() then B() with Rxjava .
is there any operator that i can use?

Comment: have you tried using flatmap ?

Comment: How to use that in kotlin???

Comment: there are lots of resources available, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471526/why-do-we-need-to-use-flatmap

Comment: i am ver new to rxjava java ....can you share any resource

Comment: you can't ask for resources on stack overflow, that's just a rule, but i have shared with you another stack overflow link which i believe will help get you started

Comment: Single.fromCallable { A() }.flatMap(it -> {B()}).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ value ->  }) { error ->

            }

Comment: not working.....